# How do I modify my COUNTIFS formula to only count the first occurrence of duplicates in a column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How To Use Countifs With Distinct Values

I have written the formula below, which counts the number of rows that match certain criteria.

```
=COUNTIFS('Lead Data'!$B:$B,CONCATENATE("*",$B$131,"*"),'Lead Data'!$C:$C,$B139,'Lead Data'!$D:$D,"20",'Lead Data'!$G:$G,"Sold",'Lead Data'!$E:$E,">="&$H$1,'Lead Data'!$E:$E,"<="&$H$1+DAY(EOMONTH($H$1,0)-1))
```

What I would like to add is it to check that in column Lead Data!F:F, its only counting the first occurence.

So for example if all the existing criteria is matched but column F has 3 duplicate values, it returns a count of 1, rather than 3.

The values in column F have no set value, so it would require to check multiple duplicates and come up with a distinct count.

Thanks

Comment: You could rewrite your countif formula with filter, unique and counta. Filter F column with all your criteria and count only uniques. Something like =counta(unique(filter(f:f,(c:c=$b139)*(d:d=20)*(another criteria))))